# How to insert date value from one table into another in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a date value from one table into another one. Unfortunately, this does not work as expected. I guess that the date value is not recognized as date and MySQL tries to convert it and messes it up.

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (name, yearID, event_date, some_value) 
    SELECT candidate_name, year_id, dateOfEvent, SUM(score) FROM T1
```

Both columns `event_date` and `dateOfEvent` are of type `DATE`

When performing the following query:

```
SELECT candidate_name, year_id, dateOfEvent, SUM(score) AS result FROM T1
```

this result is given:

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+--------+
| candidate_name | year_id | dateOfEvent | result |
+----------------+---------+-------------+--------+
|             17 |       4 |  2016-07-29 |    185 |
+----------------+---------+-------------+--------+
```

When trying the full query (as shown above), the following error message is shown:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect date value: 'Sun Jun 14 2015 12:02:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)'
```

Does anyone know the reason for that? I do not have a date like 2015-06-14... The only thing I could gess is that the `dateOfEvent` column is somehow messed up and re-interpreted as date.

Strange...

Here's the CREATE command for T2:

```
CREATE TABLE `T2` (
`name` int(11) NOT NULL,
`event_date` date NOT NULL,
`some_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`some_other_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`some_different_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`yearID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL);
```

And for T1:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
`candidate_name` int(11) NOT NULL,
`score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`zentrum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`zehntel` float DEFAULT NULL,
`year_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
dateOfEvent date NOT NULL);
```

(Both are simplified to only show relevant parts.)

Comment: Do you have any triggers on `T2` table?

Comment: No triggers on `T2`.

Comment: The `INSERT` doesn't match the table `DDL` , please fix it.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. They should match now.

Comment: Works fine here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fcec8/1 - Does a simple `INSERT INTO T2 (name, yearID, event_date, some_value)  VALUES (17,  4, ' 2016-07-29',  185 )`  work?

Comment: Yes, this insert is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are seeing this problem.  It would seem that one of the columns is simply not a `date`, presumably `dateofevent`.  The error message doesn't seem related to the types of data in the sample data you show.

However, this statement is not correct:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (name, yearID, event_date, some_value) 
    SELECT candidate_name, year_id, dateOfEvent, SUM(score)
    FROM T1;
```

You have an aggregation function but no `group by`.  So, this sums the `score` for all rows in `T1` and then gets arbitrary values for the first three columns.  Perhaps you actually intend:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (name, yearID, event_date, some_value) 
    SELECT candidate_name, year_id, dateOfEvent, SUM(score)
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY candidate_name, year_id, dateOfEvent;
```

Comment: You are right regarding the `GROUP BY`, but there's only one line in the table, so the result is still correct. I'll add the `GROUP BY` in the actual application. (I simplified the query here).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, it works fine without GROUP BY in MySQL, though it's the issue of different data types of respective columns. Still event_date is not provided in table T2.

Comment: you are right. I used wrong column names. Should be fixed now. Sorry.